# MySQL MATCH AGAINST FULL TEXT SEARCH not working dynamically with php PDO bindParam

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I implemented an ajax autocomplete search on my website with jQuery UI, and it's doing very well, but I'm having an issue with the select that does not wanna work.

The autocomplete_search_name field in the `database` is already as `FULLTEXT index`.

The `select` below is working fine in static mode, and it's the way that I want the search works, with **

```
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT autocomplete_search_name as label, url as the_link FROM product WHERE status = 'active' AND MATCH(autocomplete_search_name) AGAINST('*psico*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY MATCH(autocomplete_search_name) AGAINST('*psico*') DESC LIMIT 10");
    $stmt->execute();
    $moddados = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $moddados;
```

however, when I begin to insert the parameters dynamically with PDO bindParam or PDO quote, like the example below, the select does not work anymore. I researched a lot but couldn't find a way to solve this problem.

```
    $data['query'] = '*'.$data['query'].'*';
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT autocomplete_search_name as label, url as the_link FROM product WHERE status = 'active' AND MATCH(autocomplete_search_name) AGAINST(:query IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY MATCH(autocomplete_search_name) AGAINST(:query) DESC LIMIT 10");
    $stmt->bindParam(':query', $data['query']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $moddados = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $moddados;
```

I've tried this way below but it also does not work:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT autocomplete_search_name as label, url as the_link FROM product WHERE status = 'active' AND MATCH(autocomplete_search_name) AGAINST(CONCAT('*', :query, '*') IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY MATCH(autocomplete_search_name) AGAINST(CONCAT('*', :query, '*')) DESC LIMIT 10");
    $stmt->bindParam(':query', $data['query']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $moddados = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $moddados;
```

and also this way did not work

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT autocomplete_search_name as label, url as the_link FROM product WHERE status = 'active' AND MATCH(autocomplete_search_name) AGAINST(':query' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY MATCH(autocomplete_search_name) AGAINST(':query') DESC LIMIT 10");
    $stmt->bindParam(':query', '*' . $data['query'] . '*');
    $stmt->execute();
    $moddados = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $moddados;
```

Comment: the prepend and append the asterisk on the input is correct, but your placeholder is wrong, just use `:query` alone inside, take out the quotation and asterisk

Comment: @Ghost, i did it, but still not working

Comment: In your second example that doesn't work you still have single quotes around `:query`. They should not be there.

Comment: @Nick, I took out the single quotes around :query but it does not work anyway

Comment: I've made an update to my answer. Can you try that? Also, are you getting an error or just no results?

Comment: @Nick I saw your new update in response. Thanks for helping me, but still does not seem to work, it returns null result. And when I run the same query in phpmyadmin it works, but only with the single quotes around :querys in statement

Comment: What gives a null result? `$stmt->execute()` or `$stmt->fetchAll()`? What value is in `$data['query']`?

Comment: $stmt->fetchAll() returns null, inside the $data['query'] contains search string of a product, example 'Psycho' typed in the frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have `:query` inside single quotes and so MySQL is treating it as a string, not a parameter.

You can workaround it by either replacing `'*:query*'` with `:query` and changing the bind to:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':query', '*' . $data['query'] . '*');
```

Or you can replace `'*:query*'` with `CONCAT('*', :query, '*')`

You might also be running into the restriction (see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)) on using the same parameter name twice in one query (which only happens if you're not using emulated prepared statements). In that case you will need to change your code as follows:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT autocomplete_search_name as label, url as the_link FROM product 
                            WHERE status = 'active' AND MATCH(autocomplete_search_name) AGAINST(CONCAT('*', :query1, '*') IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
                            ORDER BY MATCH(autocomplete_search_name) AGAINST(CONCAT('*', :query2, '*')) DESC 
                            LIMIT 10");
$stmt->bindParam(':query1', $data['query']);
$stmt->bindParam(':query2', $data['query']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Hi @Nick, i replaced  the '*:query*' with asterisk to the ':query' in the statement, and used your bindParam and CONCAT, but still not working

Comment: Hi Rachel, don't use both you only need one of the alternatives (i.e. use `:query` and change the bindParam, **or** use the `CONCAT`. Did you change both occurrences? Are you getting an error or just no results?

Comment: Hi @Nick, after i put the bindParam that you suggested it returns Fatal error: Can not pass parameter 2 by reference in C: \ wamp64 \ www \ app \ models \ productModel.php on line

Comment: I improved the question, take a look if you can help me.

Comment: Hi @Nick, I saw your new update in response. Thanks for helping me, but still does not seem to work, it returns null result. And when I run the same query in phpmyadmin it works, but only with the single quotes around :querys in statement

Comment: I discovered that what was typed in the frontend was not going to the model, tank you very much

Comment: No worries I'm glad you got it figured out.